# side effects of using sleep(long) on thread instance

Tags: java, multithreading, intellij-idea

I tried following simple code

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("hello World!");
        new TestThread1().sleep(10);
    }
}

class TestThread1 extends Thread{

}
```

But in IDEA I got the following dialog.

[image]

Looks like a error but the question is why so? What is wrong with calling sleep(long) on thread instance.

`Thread.sleep(long)` also calls sleep on current thread so why cannot we do it directly or rather why should we not do it?

```
public static native void sleep(long millis) throws InterruptedException;
```

javadocs say

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease
>   execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, subject to the
>   precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers. The thread
>   does not lose ownership of any monitors.

Since it is a static function in Thread class we should be able to call it from the instance as instance has class information. Does it have to do anything to do with method being native?

Comment: It's complaining about possible side effects of the constructor being called. It's just telling you to split it as `Thread thread = new TestThread(); thread.sleep(10);` At least that's what I can surmise from the error message (never used IDEA).

Answer (score 4):

The side effect is that you created a Thread instance (and thus executing everything inside the constructor of the TestThread class). The rule is to never access or call static variables or methods through a class instance.

However, the compiler optimizes your wrong call:

```
new TestThread().sleep(10);
```

gets compiled into:

```
new TestThread(); // <---- This is the side effect!
Thread.sleep();
```

And that is what your IDE is suggesting: *if you really want it like this, please write it explicitly, in order to tell me that you know what you are doing.*

Answer (score 1):

`sleep()` is a static method so better you call it as `Thread.sleep()` not `new Thread().sleep()`

So it will call `sleep()` on current thread only not on on `new Thread()` instance

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it you are creating a `new Thread()` object to then call a static method ie `sleep()` and throw the Thread object away without even using the Thread since the call could just have been static.

This is at the very least an odd and inefficient thing to do.

Additionally I believe (although I've not seen a definite confirmation anywhere) that if you instantiate a Thread and do not call its start() method you are creating a memory leak in older versions of Java.